# Stored Procedure: Use User-Defined Variable or Call Database functions multiple times

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure that will go through and calculate different sums using 3 dynamically calculated dates in multiple queries.

If this was in code I would calculate the dates at the beginning of the function and use the local variables in the subsequent statements so that the calculation only had to happen once. I'm not very familiar with the inner workings of a MySQL database, however, so I'm not sure if the same principle applies to stored procedures.

My first attempt at the stored procedure in question looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CalcValues` (
    IN p_id int
)
BEGIN

    declare thirty datetime DEFAULT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY);

    UPDATE rpt
    SET decTarget = (SELECT SUM(decOne) 
                      FROM tblOne 
                      WHERE id = p_id AND
                            dteOne <= CURDATE() AND dteOne > thirty)
    WHERE id = p_id;

END
```

I've removed a bunch of stuff that would be processed after this section but basically I'm calculating 3 dates instead of one and using at least one of them in each query. There are a total of 10 or so queries in the procedure.

Would it be more efficient to calculate the `datetimes` at the begining of the procedure and use the local variables or to call `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)` whenever I want to use the calculated date?

Answer (score 0):

This is really more a question of programming philosophy than one of pragmatics, and the answer very much a matter of opinion. My opinion is that factoring out the function result into a local variable leads to more ***readable*** code, and I believe is what a decent optimizing compiler would do anyway. The fact that it's SQL does not, in my opinion, make a difference in this.

Comment: True enough but in this particular case performance is a huge concern. I mainly just want to make sure MySQL doesn't do anything odd with local variables inside stored procedures.